# Limiting spaces in token type definition in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm a bit confused, my XSD validating editor (IntelliJ) is allowing this to have spaces, in general I've never had a problem with IntelliJ's validation so I believe that this definition must actually mean that spaces are allowed.

But I can't figure out why.  Could someone explain what is going on and how I can limit it to no spaces?

```
 <xs:simpleType name="SymbolWord">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:minLength value="3" />
        <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9\._]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your base is `xs:token`, you're effectively specifying

```
  <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
```

and therefore causing **leading and trailing whitespace to be trimmed**.

Change your base to `xs:string` to force leading and trailing whitespace to be *invalid* for `SymbolType` per your expectations.

If you're seeing *embedded* whitespace being allowed, then post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); that should not be happening.